# z-index not working properly as expected?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to make a book that flips on click on both sides.
When I click a page, I check first the direction and flip it to left if it's not to right. I change the z-index as well to keep the order.

I have a problem.
When i flip the page back to right from left, z-index is applied correctly
but on the screen I see the changed applied a few seconds later.
If i console log the z-index, I see the value getting updated correctly.
I don't know what I'm missing. can anyone tell me? thank you.

```js
const book = document.querySelector('.book');
book.addEventListener('click', e => {
    if (e.target.attributes['data-position'].value !== 'left') {
        e.target.setAttribute('data-position', 'left');
        e.target.classList.remove('flip-to-right');
        e.target.classList.add('flip-to-left');
        setTimeout(() => {
            console.log (e.target.attributes['data-position'].value);
            // e.target.style.zIndex = e.target.attributes['data-index'].value*(-1);
            e.target.style.zIndex = 1;
        }, 1000);
    }
    else {
        e.target.style.zIndex = e.target.attributes['data-index'].value;
        e.target.classList.remove('flip-to-left');
        e.target.classList.add('flip-to-right');
        e.target.setAttribute('data-position', 'right');
    }
})
```

```css
* {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
    height: 100vh;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    background: yellow;
    perspective: 1000px;
}

.book {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.book:hover .cover{
    /* transform: rotateX(10deg) rotateY(-180deg); */
}

.book:hover .page{
    /* transform: rotateX(10deg) rotateY(-180deg); */
    /* z-index: 2; */
}

.flip-to-left {
    transform: rotateX(10deg) rotateY(-180deg);
}

.flip-to-right {
    transform: rotateX(10deg) rotateY(0deg);
}

.cover {
    z-index: 7;
    /* transform: rotateX(10deg) rotateY(-180deg); */
    transition: all 3s;
}

.page-1 {
    z-index: 5;
}
.page-2 {
    z-index: 4;
}
.page-3 {
    z-index: 3;
}
.page-4 {
    z-index: 2;
}
.last-page {
    z-index: 1;
}

.back-cover {
    z-index: 0;
}

.back-cover,
.cover{
    height: 300px;
    width: 260px;
    background-color: blue;
    border-radius: 10px;
    position: absolute;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 10px gray;
    /* transform: rotateX(10deg); */
    transform-origin: center left;
}

.last-page,
.page {
    height: 280px;
    width: 250px;
    background: white;
    position: absolute;
    border-radius: 10px;
    /* transform: rotateX(10deg); */
    transform-origin: center left;
    transition: all 3s;

    /* z-index: -1; */
}

/* .page:nth-child(2) {
    transition-duration: 3s;
}

.page:nth-child(3) {
    transition-duration: 2.6s;
}
.page:nth-child(4) {
    transition-duration: 2.2s;
}
.page:nth-child(5) {
    transition-duration: 1.8s;
}
.page:nth-child(6) {
    transition-duration: 1.4s;
}

.book:hover .page:nth-child(2) {
    transition-duration: 6s;
}

.book:hover .page:nth-child(2) {
    transition-duration: 6s;
}
.book:hover .page:nth-child(3) {
    transition-duration: 5.6s;
}
.book:hover .page:nth-child(4) {
    transition-duration: 5.2s;
}
.book:hover .page:nth-child(5) {
    transition-duration: 4.8s;
}
.book:hover .page:nth-child(6) {
    transition-duration: 4.4s;
} */

.last-page > div {
    width: 150px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    margin: 20px auto;
    background-color: green;
    position: relative;
    /* z-index: -1; */
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="js.js" defer> </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="book">
        <div class="cover" data-index="7" data-position="right"> cover </div>
        <div class="page page-1" data-index="6" data-position="right"> page 1</div>
        <div class="page page-2" data-index="5" data-position="right"> page 2</div>
        <div class="page page-3" data-index="4" data-position="right"> page 3</div>
        <div class="page page-4" data-index="3" data-position="right"> page 4</div>
        <div class="last-page" data-index="2" data-position="right">page 5</div>
        <div class="back-cover" data-index="1" data-position="right"></div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is `transition: all 3s;`. You're animating *all* properties, including the `zIndex`. If you change it to `transition: transform 3s;` (in both places) it seems to behave. You might need to add more properties, I didn't check.

Comment: that was absolutely right.. thank you for enlightening this nob!

Answer (score 0):

please refer the attached video
update the following css and try to run and check.

```
* {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
    height: 100vh;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    background: yellow;
    perspective: 1000px;
}

.book {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.book:hover .cover{
    /* transform: rotateX(10deg) rotateY(-180deg); */
}

.book:hover .page{
    /* transform: rotateX(10deg) rotateY(-180deg); */
    /* z-index: 2; */
}

.flip-to-left {
    transform: rotateX(10deg) rotateY(-180deg);
}

.flip-to-right {
    transform: rotateX(10deg) rotateY(0deg);
}

.cover {
    z-index: 7;
    /* transform: rotateX(10deg) rotateY(-180deg); */
    transition: all 3s;
}
.cover{
  z-index: 0;
}
.page-1 {
    z-index: 2;
}
.page-2 {
    z-index: 2;
}
.page-3 {
    z-index: 2;
}
.page-4 {
    z-index: 2;
}
.last-page {
    z-index: 2;
}

.back-cover {
    z-index: 3;
}

.back-cover,
.cover{
    height: 300px;
    width: 260px;
    background-color: blue;
    border-radius: 10px;
    position: absolute;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 10px gray;
    /* transform: rotateX(10deg); */
    transform-origin: center left;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}

.last-page,
.page {
    height: 280px;
    width: 250px;
    background: linear-gradient(272deg, #ffffff, #858181);
    position: absolute;
    border-radius: 10px;
    /* transform: rotateX(10deg); */
    transform-origin: center left;
    transition: all 3s;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}


.last-page > div {
    width: 150px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    margin: 20px auto;
    background-color: green;
    position: relative;
    /* z-index: -1; */
}
```